# Handle huge array with php and mongo

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, bigdata

These are my current tools: PHP, Mongo, Mongo in memory.

We have a feature that could reach at its peak to 2 arrays of 20M emails.

Now we need to compare those 2 arrays and find the diffs between them.

1. How would you suggest storing this list of emails in mongo?

   1. one document with a big array inside it (not valid, 16mb limit)
   2. or several documents that each has an email
2. How would you suggest doing the comparison of the 2 lists?

If I do it in memory on php code, 1M emails in an array is approx 140mb
so 20M emails will be huge 2.8GB of memory

**For the comments below:**

These are lists of usernames, ie:

- `['john', 'dan', 'sarah']`
- `['dan', 'samantha', 'donald']`

I want to compare those lists and remove the duplicate, so I'll get:

- `['john', 'sarah']`
- `['samantha', 'donald']`

You can see Dan was removed, as he is on both lists.

Comment: There is already a limit for a document in mongodb. A document cannot be more than 16MB.  You can use a hybrid model of those two options. Or you can do something entirely diffirent based on situation. For example how will those 20M emails will come? What do you mean with diffs between them? Will those array be populated in future or just static arrays. etc..

Comment: Thanks @barbakini just updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Don't store and compare strings itself.

1. Add a new column in your table, call it `hash`.
2. This `hash` column must be able to keep at least `uint32` number (unsigned integer, 32 bits).
3. Use [crc32](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) as a hash.
4. Load/compare hashes instead of strings now.

Comment: so comparing numbers is cheaper... but I still need the username from that hash? and still how would you handle those big numbers?

Comment: @TzookBarNoy what did you try to ask with "but I still need the username from that hash?" question? If you meant that you need to convert hash to name (or email again) - you have a table for that.

Comment: @TzookBarNoy "and still how would you handle those big numbers" - where are big numbers? Is int32 is a big number for you?

Comment: it wasn't a question :) I need those usernames. So you are saying to store in mongo per document the hash and the email. And by big numbers, I mean for the amount of records to handle, 20M. would you do the comparison?

Comment: Once you have all the hashes (basically, numbers) in memory, you can just use `array_diff` and `array_intersect` or whatever.

Comment: @TzookBarNoy Ah, I'm sure that it's possible to split your big task (load & compare) into the sequence of small ones. It's actually depends on why and how did you get these 2 lists but in general you are able to create a table (or even a file) that will store fully your first list and then you'll iterate through your second array (let's say you must compare 100 million items). But instead of load such big array into the memory, cut it into 100-200-300 small arrays (chunks) and check each of it with your first list (table/file).

Comment: Thanks, but even when I sort the lists and trying to load them in chunks. There is the option I could load M of items in memory instead of 100-300 a time, because I can get one item from list1 but he would be in the end of list2. Maybe there is some kind of mongo query or something

Comment: @TzookBarNoy You are able to use hashes instead of strings and it's possible to compare items without full loading of an array into the memory. I'll try once again with a simple example: prepare your first list. That means that you must write it to the file, line by line (don't load full list from database, use chunks). Then prepare your second list: load a small amount of items (1 million or less). Then read few lines from the first file and check if it has anything from your second list. Read file till the end. There's no any "item from list1 but he would be in the end of list2" problem.

Comment: Thanks @user1597430 I'll try to dig in to your idea. I still dont see the benefit of the hash, as I read it is possible to have duplicates of 1% in 10K records. My usernames are all unique

Comment: @TzookBarNoy :-\\\\\ Man, your string consumes at least 1 byte per 1 character and extra 1 byte for NULL-char to show it's end. Hash - it's uint32 number, even if you use PHP x64 and you have int64 for all numbers - it's only 8 bytes per 1 number. Do you really think that your average email has less than 8 bytes? Doesn't matter is it unique or not, it's just cheaper.

Comment: OK will get a a hash for numbers that will be unique for all my usernames, and then I'll do your suggestion :)

Comment: @TzookBayNoy I'll try the last time to show you the main idea. Imagine that you have 2 very big files. Lest say `file_1` and `file_2`, your task is to find same lines in both of them. Your idea is to read both files into the memory and compare them immediately. My idea is to use two nested loops: in the first one we read some lines from `file_1`, in the second one we read lines from `file_2` and compare them and continue reading `file_2` till the end. You may notice here that `file_2` will be read many times when `file_1` only once (full). That's how you are able to avoid memory limits.